# How much sense does it make to use a double-buffering in a text editor display chain?

Tags: c++, winapi

Ok, so this might be kinda stupid, I dunno know, but I was wondering if there would be any sense in double buffering a text editor. I was thinking of printing each character to a backbuffer one by one, or maybe word by word to a back buffer and then presenting the updated part of the text to the screen using BitBlt? Would this be any good? Sorry if this was stupid, I'll take this question of if it's not up to standards.

Regards,
Devjeet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any modern OS / window system where this sort of memory or frame buffer access would be practical - or yield any improvement in performance. As far as text goes, high quality, true-type font rendering was solved long ago. Most window systems (X11 / Quartz / Aero) implement font caching, and use the compositing capabilities of the graphics hardware.

A more immediate answer is that a text editor is spending most of its time waiting for user input. It's unlikely that the rendering is a bottleneck. FWIW, I'm glad you're thinking about performance on this level.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how your program is structured, but generally speaking GUI-centric applications (such as your text editor) will do good to utilize double-buffering to avoid those nasty flickerings...

Call BitBlt() with the screen (I call it "live") dc as late as possible.